# Google dataflow job to read avro files from Cloud storage based on file patterns

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

Say given the files in gcs stored in the following formats:
-.avro . Trying to use read files in google dataflow job using apache beam's FileIO.matchAll library to read files based on timestamp interval.
Example, File in gcs :

```
   gs://test-bucket/abc_20200101000000.txt
    gs://test-bucket/abc_20200201000000.txt
    gs://test-bucket/abc_20200301000000.txt
```

Now we want to fetch all the files who are greater than timestamp 20200101000000 till current timestamp, what file pattern can i use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a regex but you should be able to add a `ParDo` to your pipeline that follows `FileIO.matchAll` to filter elements (of type `MatchResult.Metadata`) based on the filename (`MatchResult.Metadata.resourceId()`).